# Why are my planes transparent?

Tags: retopology

[image: troll]

I am learning retopology, but the first problem starts at the beginning.

Somehow my basic plane is transparent in object-mode. In edit-mode the outlines disappear even, leaving just the origin point visible. In Material-Preview all works fine. Nonetheless: how can I make the Plane visible in Solid View?
Here´s the file
https://www.dropbox.com/s/d2wttf1gugfblrm/troll.blend?dl=0

Comment: From given screen it is just guesing ... in object mode doesnt seems to be transparent, left corner is solid, looks more like hiden by Troll (thanks to wrong snapping)? if you move plane far from Troll is it transparent too?

Comment: Hm, actually when I move the plane away from the troll it isn´t transparent anymore.

Comment: if you provide blend file we can check it out

Comment: voila: https://www.dropbox.com/s/d2wttf1gugfblrm/troll.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

you used a shrinkwrap modifier which makes the object move "inside" the other object.

If you want to see it you have several possibilities:

- increase offset in modifier

[image]

- hide the other object

[image]

- use wireframe

[image]