# Why can I see an Object through another?

Tags: modeling, retopology

I am still trying to learn retopology and still struggling with the beginning (like you can see here [Why are my planes transparent?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/248171/why-are-my-planes-transparent?noredirect=1#comment422123_248171)) The problem is very basic.[image: cubes and mask]

The blue cube has viewport visibility "front" checked. I can´t explain myself why or how to fix it. I would help a lot if the problem was solved in my first post, where the base plane is transparent to the sculpt in Object-Mode and even invisible in Edit-Mode. Here´s the file
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nlliywkjrhtv1ht/new_repto.blend?dl=0

Comment: would u provide blend file? and yes, i have problems understanding what you mean and what you want, but maybe the blend file make this more clear....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the plane through another object, because you checked "front" in viewport display:

[image]

By this Blender shows your object always "in front" although it isn't there in reality.

"Normally" you wouldn't use this option.

But this option is very helpful if you work with armatures because the "normally" are inside the meshes and then you wouldn't see the bones and you wouldn't know where they are.

example: checking "front" on and off

[image]

Comment: I kinda forgot about that; thanks!

Comment: No problem! You are welcome!

Comment: Could you also check my other file here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/248171/why-are-my-planes-transparent ? It needs another solution...